# Xcode 14 - Universal App Target - Can't Run watchOS App (But it does compile)

Tags: xcode, watchos

I added support to my universal target for watchOS, I then made sure the app compiles successfully for watchOS. However, when I try and run the app on the simulator, I get the error:

> Please try again later.
> com.xxx.xxx: Missing WKCompanionAppBundleIdentifier key in WatchKit 2.0 app's > Info.plist

This doesn't make sense to me because there is no companion app, it's just a watch only app at that point? I've tried adding the WKCompanionAppBundleIdentifier key to the plist but it then tells me it can't find the companion app's bundle identifier.

Little lost here, any insight on how to get universal targets to run on the watch in Xcode 14?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am facing the same issue in Xcode 15.